# How can I make a one page websites on joomla?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

i'm trying out joomla! CMS, and in my job we're very fond of one-page sites. Is there any way of making a fully functional website with it? The main reason we need the CMS is because of the way the client wants to update they're webpage.

Comment: what you've tried so far?

Comment: Trying to use only the homepage, and build the website with articles and modules, but im limited to about 3-4 useful module positions thay look good, and article layout is too easy to mess up.

Comment: Well, You have to use javascript to link menu to one page design pages and set all content to one page and define it as homepage or call it in your theme file as home page! OR Purchase a good theme with one page functions from popular vendor

Comment: What do you mean by a one page site? DO you mean a very long page people will scroll down?  
Why do you feel you are limited in the number of module positions? I've seen some really nice long page Joomla designs but if you are going to put constraints on like that you aren't going to use positions in a way that works for you, that's going to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok before you do anything, have a real think to yourself, is Joomla really the best option? Your client requires a 1 page website, therefore what would be the point in loading a full blown CMS just for that. Joomla, when zipped up, is more or less 8MB. Out of all honestly, I would even find the likes of Wordpress still too big for a project of this size.

What I would really recommend is having a look round on the web for a very small CMS that simply includes a small backend with the ability to create, update and delete articles.

Have a look at this for example:

http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/

This would be a brilliant way to start. It has a small backend for you to manage articles, and you can start building up a completely custom template, exactly to your client's liking. I'm not too sure on the programming skills but if you're fairly new to it, then this would be a good place to start and gain knowledge.

Given that the above is what I would personally recommend, you may not want to do that or may not have the time, therefore if you really want to stick with Joomla, you should find a template that fits your needs in regards to module positions. Else you can add your own custom positions to the template. Have a read through the documentation as it will give you the necessary information

Hope this helps

Comment: I basically agree, but I think the reality is room to grow. You can start a Joomla site as a one page site, never let the client even see the backend, but then when they want a contact form or something you have the infrastructure there.  Most $5 hosting will hold dozens of copies of Joomla so I don't think storage is the issue.

Comment: @Elin - true, It is always good to allow room for growth in the future, however I think a lot of planning should go into the type of site one wants before hand. If you believe the site will grow in the future, then yes, Joomla would be a good way to start

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution myself for quite a while. I came up with the following two soutions:

1. Like @mattosmat said for a joomla one page site the simplest solution actually is it to declare one section as the main componenent and create the other section with cusom-made joomla modules.
2. Use wordpress with the advanced field plugin to create a single-page website.

Actually if a clients wish is it to create a single page website with cck and cms features i create these projects in wordpress and not in joomla anymore in my opinion its the wrong plattform.

Answer (score -1):

I Have One Word!!!

BOOTSTRAP!!!! IS the way to go.. simple,succinct,beginner friendly. Doesnt matter if you really make it in Joomla! or anything else.

And for head start, look up "Scrollspy" in Bootstrap.

Comment: I think what @TianRB meant to ask is if it was possible to do this at a higher level. I myself have given it some thought and so far the only thing I could come up with is to use modules instead of articles to present the information I want.

Comment: I think he might was looking for a solutions how you can build a one-page in a joomla backend without any complicated 3rd party tools.
So this is actually impossible.

Comment: @Peesen87 Listen dear, I donot know how much exposure you have had, but there are a lot of websites & templates out there in Joomla! with a single page design, here is a cookie for you. http://demo.joomlaxtc.com/dub2/

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib Look at the code of this site. My god what a module chaos. If the customer wants to add a new section to the single page? Where is the content-box modul in joomla to create customized boxes based on the project? There is NO solution to create easy maintainable single page websites in joomla. Of course you can create single page websites but no customer has any chance to edit it and add new sections. So what do you think?

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib Still waiting for your answer

Comment: @Peesen87 Ofc, The article and sections functionality of Joomla! is not applicable here, since they are there to create multipage websites, and in order to create a single page website you shall have to use modules, and it may seem like "chaos" to you, but for me its perfectly normal. Even when I wasn't really good in Joomla! in my early days, I found creating / updating the modules as easy as working with articles. Furthermore, any person who can work with modules in Joomla! can surely create modules and assign them to the module-positions provided on the example I mentioned above. IMHO.